# Fill Color on ConvexHull OpenCV

Tags: opencv, colors, convex-hull

Everyone, please help me. I have a problem. 
I make a Convex Hull detection from image.

Then, i have a problem to fill a color on area within the boundary of ConvexHull.

**Is there someone who can help me to fill a color on area within the boundary of ConvexHull?**

Please help me with implementation on source code.

I use OpenCV 2.3.

This is a source code:

```
 #include "stdafx.h" 
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 Mat src; Mat src_gray;
 int thresh = 240;
 int max_thresh = 255;
 RNG rng(12345);

 /// Function header
 void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
   /// Load source image and convert it to gray
   src = imread( "kubis1.jpg", 1 );

   /// Convert image to gray and blur it
   cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
   blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

   /// Create Window
   char* source_window = "Source";
   namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( source_window, src );

   createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
   thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

   waitKey(0);
   return(0);
 }

 /** @function thresh_callback */
 void thresh_callback(int, void* )
 {
   Mat src_copy = src.clone();
   Mat threshold_output;
   vector<vector<Point> > contours;
   vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

   /// Detect edges using Threshold
   threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

   /// Find contours
   findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

   /// Find the convex hull object for each contour
   vector<vector<Point> >hull( contours.size() );
   for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
      {  convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false );
   }

   /// Draw contours + hull results
   Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
   for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
        Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
        drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
        drawContours( drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
      }

   /// Show in a window
   namedWindow( "Hull demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Hull demo", drawing );
 }
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: My problem: Help me to fill a color on area within the boundary of ConvexHull.

Answer (score 13):

You should use [`drawContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours) function with negative ’thickness’ parameter:

> The function draws contour outlines in the image if thickness >= 0 or
>   fills the area bounded by the contours if thickness <= 0